# Workflow extension that doesn't run

Tags: acumatica

In an Acumatica code extension, I am attempting to create a workflow extension for BusinessAccountWorkflow.  It adds a few actions that I want to suppress. My extension’s Configure method override basically doesn’t do anything, so that the base method doesn’t create actions.  My override method doesn’t seem to be running, though, because the actions still appear, and my breakpoint isn’t hit. Below is the extension.  What could I be missing to get this override to run?

```
public class BusinessAccountWorkflowExt : PXGraphExtension<BusinessAccountWorkflow, 
BusinessAccountMaint>
{
    public static bool IsActive() => false;

    public override void Configure(PXScreenConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var context = configuration
            .GetScreenConfigurationContext<BusinessAccountMaint, BAccount>();

        context.AddScreenConfigurationFor(screen =>
        {
            return screen;
        });

        //context.RemoveScreenConfigurationFor();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, for debugging you have to publish the customization with the DLL in it and then attach while publish is running and you should be able to catch it at with a breakpoint on the configure method. Its hard, I wish there was a button we could push to rerun workflow config methods on the "apply updates" screen or something

Comment: Thanks Kyle.  I did start noticing the breakpoint would be hit in certain circumstances, like DLL load, and was able to debug a bit further.  I also noticed since I posted this that there are more levels of extension for Business Account than I first thought, and needed to extend multiple levels and extensions of other extensions.  However, no matter what I've done so far, I haven't been able to hide the actions that I'm trying to.  I might create another topic for this, though.

Answer (score 1):

Tony, your code sample sets IsActive to false which should disable the graph extension.  This doesn't exactly seem to behave the same on workflows as it does normal graph extensions, so I'm not sure if it causes any harm.

Next, I think you really want to use UpdateScreenConfigurationFor instead of AddScreenConfigurationFor.  This lets you tap into the defined workflow and add actions or alter conditions.  For instance, you can update an action to be .IsHiddenAlways() if you don't want it to show in any condition.  (Alternatively, you can hide it via permissions and never have to code for that!)

Take a look at standard workflow source code that ends _ApprovalWorkflow.cs for examples of how Acumatica updates an existing workflow to insert Approve and Reject functionality as well as altering transitions to inject the Pending approval state.

To be able to add your own actions, it's pretty simple code.  Below is an example of how I injected my own actions into the menu for the Sales Order Entry screen, which honestly has a crazy complex workflow overall.  However, always adding my buttons to the menu doesn't require touching any of that standard complexity.

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.WorkflowAPI;
using SSCS;

namespace PX.Objects.SO.Workflow.SalesOrder
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Workflow_SSCS : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public static bool IsActive() => true;  // Insert your own logic here

        #region Initialization
        public override void Configure(PXScreenConfiguration config)
        {
            Configure(config.GetScreenConfigurationContext<SOOrderEntry, SOOrder>());
        }

        protected virtual void Configure(WorkflowContext<SOOrderEntry, SOOrder> context)
        {
            context.UpdateScreenConfigurationFor(screen =>
            {
                return screen
                    .WithActions(actions =>
                    {
                        actions.Add<SOOrderEntry_Extension>(g => g.RecordOutage, a => a.WithCategory(PredefinedCategory.Actions));
                    });
            });
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Where I added actions in the above sample using actions.Add, you would want to use actions.Update to alter the definition of the action.  This is where you would put **.IsHiddenWhen(*condition*)** or **.IsHiddenAlways()**.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'll try updating the hide conditions and see if that helps.